# Can a Kalman filter deal with unexpectedly noisy measurements?

Tags: statistics, variance, kalman-filter

I've been working with Kalman filter for a while. In this particular case I'm trying to estimate the velocity or rising air at a specific location (a square km) on a hot summers' day. I expect the velocity to be more or less constant during the day.

Multiple measurements are performed during the day (by aircraft flying over the square km). I have some idea of the accuracy of the measurements performed by the aircraft, but there are many factors that can influence the situation that are hard for me to quantify.
I figured I might be able to derive something from the spread of the samples around the model (in my case a fixed value) that I use for prediction in the kalman filter?

I wonder if there are ways for a Kalman filter to take into account how well the data seems to fit the model? Are there ways to take into account the variance between the samples and the kalman estimates? If so, how is this called? And how is this used in practice?

Comment: Does the aircraft take multiple measurements when flying over the area?

Comment: Yes, each aircraft takes a measurement every second.

Comment: As long as the noise is Gaussian, [it should](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/3032/kalman-filter-vs-hough-transform/3046#3046).

Comment: So you want to use all measurements of one flyby to estimate the noise covariance of that flyby?

Comment: All measurements, as long as they fall within that specific square km, are considered equal. I perform no grouping per flight or any other criteria. So I want to use all measurements in that particular square km to estimate the noise covariance.